# Is sim a shell script command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I was creating a `sym-link` for practice in Ubuntu 14.04. I meant to use this command:

```
 ln -s ../fun dir1/fun-sym
```

It was taken from a book I am using. Except I used `sim` at the end by mistake. So the last was `/fun-sim`. The command was accepted and it seemed to make 2 links. I also put in the correct command. Using

```
 ls -l
```

it did show both as being links. They lines look the same except for the sim and sym.

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 julios julios    3 Aug 27 12:58 fun-sim -> fun
```

and

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 julios julios    3 Aug 27 13:11 fun-sym -> fun.
```

Using this command

```
 ls -li
```

it showed one number difference in the inode, 684226 & 684227. I am learning and lost but it caught my attention when it seemed to create a link. I thought there would have been an error message of some kind. No idea how to test it. I tried

```
 man sim
```

and got this response:

```
 No manual entry for sim.
```

That seems to be the answer for no such command. I got the same response for `go`, `jump` and `please`. No problem was caused. What caught my attention was that it worked at all when it should have failed. Maybe one of the ways programming errors happen, typos. Anyway, it was interesting to me but I am just trying to find my way around the command line.

Comment: The inode is just a representation of where the actual file lives on the disk, `fun-sim` and `fun-sym` are two separate files, so you have two different inodes

Answer (score 4):

No it isn't.

As you said, `man sim` doesn't exist.

And running `sim` gives

```
No command 'sim' found, but there are 23 similar ones
```

In your example 'sim' was only used as part of a file name. 'fun-sym' could have been almost anything, it has no effect on the command. Since it is only the file you are creating, it only has to be a valid file name.

All that you did was instead of linking to `../fun dir1/fun-sym` you linked to  `../fun dir1/fun-sim`

This command still worked because when you are using `ln` to create symbolic links (i.e. `-s` option) the target does not have to exist, except for hard links [Kudos @TheSchwa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516844/is-sim-a-shell-script-command/516853?noredirect=1#comment701453_516853)

Comment: @TheSchwa edited.